# Get ID of the element I hover over with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of  elements that look like this:

```
<span class='tags' id='html'>html</span>
<span class='tags' id='php'>php</span>
<span class='tags' id='sql'>sql</span>
```

How would I get the name of the id of the one I hover over, so I could output something like "You're hovering over the **html** tag". (What I want to do isn't that arbitrary, but I do need to get the name of the tag the user hovers over in order to do it.)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[mouseover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mouseover) should do the trick.

```
$('.tags').mouseover(function() {
   alert(this.id);
});
```

Note that if you want to know when the mouse leaves as well, you can use [hover](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover).

Comment: That displays an empty alert box. =/.

Comment: Oops, I had two classes named 'tags' on accident; I made one for a list and one to format the tag. hehe.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
$('.tags').hover(
  function() { console.log( 'hovering on' , $(this).attr('id') ); },
  function() {}
);
```

Second empty function is for mouse out, you'll probably want to do something on that event as well.

Answer (score 2):

These solutions still returned an empty alert for me. For me, following worked when I handled the event object passed to the hover function:

```
$(".input-box").hover(function(eventObj) { 
    alert(eventObj.target.id);  
});
```

[Source of this solution](https://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2)

Answer (score 1):

```html
Use this one:- 

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("p").hover(function(){
        
            //if get onhover id
            alert("NOW GET ON HOVER ID NAME:--"+" "+this.id);
            
            //if get onhover class
            alert("NOW GET ON HOVER CLASS NAME:--"+" "+$(this).attr('class'));
            
            
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p class="getclass" id="get_class_id" >Hover the mouse</p>

    </body>
    </html>
```