# get what element the mouse is over with the mousemove event on the body

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you use the `mousemove` event on the body tag. Is it possible to get what element in the html the mouse is currently over.

```
$('body').mousemove(function (e) {

var details = e; // can e.something return what element the mouse cursor is over?

console.log(details);

});
```

Comment: You could try http://stackoverflow.com/a/1777238/1625955, but I think you might have to target more then the body tag.

Comment: Element ID or element type i.e div, input etc?

Comment: I hate to mention it, but the `mousemove` event fires an awful lot, this is likely to show your page down quite a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use event.target

for getting id use

```
var id = event.target.id;
```

use can also check using this

```
 var $target = $(event.target);
 if ($target.is("a")) {
        }
```

Comment: Also: var id = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY).id

Answer (score 5):

Use e.target. For more information, you can check [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) documentation.

```
$('body').mousemove(function (e) {
     var details = e.target; // can e.something return what element the mouse cursor is over?
     console.log(details);
});
```

Here is the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/PaX7b/1/