# Need index number of item in array on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, jquery-hover

I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I'm working on what should be a simple project. I'm stuck though and I'd love some opinions on ways to get a solution. 
I have a short products array like:

```
var products = [
   {
    name: "paper",
    price: 2.00,
    description: "White College-ruled Paper, 100 sheets",
    location: "Aisle 5"
   },
   {
    name: "pens",
    price: 5.00,
    description: "10 Pack, Black Ink Ball Point Pens"
    location: "Aisle 2"
   },
   {
    name: "paper clips",
    price: 0.50,
    description: "Silver Paper Clips, 100 count"
    location: "Aisle 6"
   }
  ]
```

I'm looping through this array using JS and printing the results to the page in a DIV with id of "output".

```
function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
  product = products[i];
  message += '<div class="col-md-4" id="prod-block">';
  message += '<p id="prod-description">' + product.name + ' ' + product.description + '</p>';
  message += '<h2 id="price">$' + product.price  + '</h2>';
  message += '</div>'
}
print(message);
```

All of this works just fine. I have my products on the page. Now, what I want is when the mouse hovers over any of the item divs, to show additional information (such as location) in a separate div. 
My question is - how do you identify the index number of the item that is being hovered over? As of now, the index number only exists in my for loop and I can't figure out how to access it in a different function.

Again, my knowledge is limited, so I'm not sure if writing the HTML in a for loop is even the best way to do this. I really appreciate any advice or criticism!!

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context, you are rendering invalid HTML markup

Comment: Good point! I'll change those to classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that should help.

I updated your list to include an id attribute and I used that to assign a `data` attribute to the `div` that is being created. On hover it looks for the `data-prodid` and displays that in the `additional` section.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/press/a779n02m/)

```js
var products = [{
    id: 0,
    name: "paper",
    price: 2.00,
    description: "White College-ruled Paper, 100 sheets",
    location: "Aisle 5"
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: "pens",
    price: 5.00,
    description: "10 Pack, Black Ink Ball Point Pens",
    location: "Aisle 2"
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: "paper clips",
    price: 0.50,
    description: "Silver Paper Clips, 100 count",
    location: "Aisle 6"
  }],
  message = '';

function print(message) {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i += 1) {
  product = products[i];
  message += '<div data-prodid="' + product.id + '" class="col-md-4" id="prod-block">';
  message += '<p id="prod-description">' + product.name + ' ' + product.description + '</p>';
  message += '<h2 id="price">$' + product.price + '</h2>';
  message += '</div>'
}
print(message);

$('.col-md-4').hover(function() {
  $('#additional').html($(this).data('prodid'));
});
```

## Also

The javascript you posted has an error in your products variable and message was never declared.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is genius. Yeah, I made some sample code to try to make explaining it easier, but I must have made a mistake. I think this will absolutely work for what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

try to add a tip tool as and when you create the div with the index number you want.

`<div title="The index number">`

Answer (score 0):

There is something really wrong in your code: the abuse of `id`. Many elements will have the id `prod-block`, `prod-description` but an `id` [has to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#adef-id).

Doing this, you can easily detect which element is hovered just by checking the id. There is multiple techniques to do that, if you want to learn jQuery this is really easy to start [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777210/get-id-of-the-element-i-hover-over-with-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you could use data() to define the data attribute of the DOM element, but you shoudl also use jQuery to add this element to the DOM.

```
$.each(products, function(i, product) {
    // Create DOM element
    var _ = $('<div class="col-md-4" id="prod-block">'
        + '<p id="prod-description">' + product.name + ' ' + product.description + '</p>'
        + '<h2 id="price">$' + product.price  + '</h2>'
        + '</div>');
    // Set product data
    _.data("product", product);
    // Add element to the DOM
    $("#output").append(_);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options here, such as adding the data as an attribute of the element, but I believe your best option is to create the HTML elements explicitly so you can attach event listeners to them, then append them to the DOM; this would be instead of setting the innerHTML of the output div element to a string representation of the desired HTML.

```js
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var hoverOutput = document.getElementById("hovertext");
for (var i = 0, len = products.length; i < len; i++) {
  product = products[i];
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "col-md-4";
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<p class="prod-description">' + product.name + ' ' + product.description + '</p><h4 class="price">$' + product.price + '</h4>';
  (function() {
    var num = i;
    var target = hoverOutput;
    newDiv.onmouseover = function() {
      target.innerHTML = num;
    };
  })();
  output.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

Check out the working example below:

```js
var products = [{
  name: "paper",
  price: 2.00,
  description: "blah blah",
  location: "aisle 5"
}, {
  name: "paper clips",
  price: 0.5,
  description: "blah bloo blab",
  location: "aisle 6"
}];
var output = document.getElementById("output");
var hoverOutput = document.getElementById("hovertext");
for (var i = 0, len = products.length; i < len; i++) {
  product = products[i];
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.className = "col-md-4";
  newDiv.innerHTML = '<p class="prod-description">' + product.name + ' ' + product.description + '</p><h4 class="price">$' + product.price + '</h4>';
  (function() {
    var num = i;
    var target = hoverOutput;
    newDiv.onmouseover = function() {
      target.innerHTML = num;
    };
  })();
  output.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```css
#hovertext {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  min-height: 10px;
}
#output div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.col-md-4{line-height:.2em;}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<div id="hovertext">Hover over an item to see its index here</div>
```