# get data on mousehover for different id

Tags: php, jquery

I have a listing of products each with differnt ID. Now on frontend I want to get prodouct data(say, name,price and a addtocart button) on mousover.
Here is my code:
This is in loop to get all products:

HTML:

```
<div class="prod">
   <a class="product-image pi_470" title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html"><img height="135" width="135" alt="Cushion Tsavorites" src="/small_image.jpg"></a>
   <div style="display: none; margin: -65px 0px 0px 5px; position: absolute; z-index: 30;" class="mouse_hover_470">
      <input type="hidden" id="prod_id" value="470">             
      <h2 class="product-name"><a title="Cushion Tsavorites" href="/tsavorite/cushion-tsavorites-1328.html">Cushion Tsavorites</a></h2>
      <div class="price-box">
         <span id="product-price-470" class="regular-price">
         <span class="price">$387.15</span>                                   
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
         <button onclick="setLocation('http://dev614.trigma.us/chocolate/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2RldjYxNC50cmlnbWEudXMvY2hvY29sYXRlL2luZGV4LnBocC90c2F2b3JpdGUuaHRtbA,,/product/470/form_key/4BR7w0TqeeO9AC0g/')" class="button btn-cart" title="Add to Cart" type="button"><span><span>Add to Cart</span></span></button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  var bla = jQuery('#prod_id').val();
  jQuery(".pi_" + bla).mouseover(function() {
    //alert("hello");
    jQuery(".mouse_hover_" + bla).css("display", "block");
  });

  jQuery(".pi_" + bla).mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(".mouse_hover_" + bla).css("display", "none");
  });

});
```

But Iam getting only data of first product on mouseover. Its not working for rest of products

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get ID of the element I hover over with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777210/get-id-of-the-element-i-hover-over-with-jquery)

Comment: Please post **`html`** instead of `php`

Comment: why cant you use class instead of ID? ID should be unique, if you have more that one same ID jquery will consider only first one.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are executing the above block of code in a loop, once per each product. In that case the problem is `jQuery('#prod_id').val();` it will always return the value of first element with id `prod_id`.

In your case you don't have to do that, you can

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.prod .product-image').hover(function () {
        $(this).next().show();
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().hide();
    })
});
```

Comment: The code continue to blink as long as I hover on the .product-image. I need to make it stabel as I had another jquery click function button that open up a popup. Due to blinking jquery on button is not working

Answer (score 1):

You can use `each()` function in jQuery

**NOTE:** Instead of using `id="prod_id"`, use `class`, i.e  `class="prod_id"`. Since you told that the `div` is dynamically created it is using the **same id attribute**

Now loop the product div on `ready` function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.prod').each(function(){
     var bla = jQuery('.prod_id').val();
    jQuery(".pi_" + bla).on('mouseover',function() {
    //alert("hello");
      jQuery(".mouse_hover_" + bla).css("display", "block");
    });

    jQuery(".pi_" + bla).on('mouseout',function() {
      jQuery(".mouse_hover_" + bla).css("display", "none");
    });
  });
 });
```

You can checkout this **[jQuery each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)**

Comment: If I have 25 or 50 products on the page, then jquery function will be created 50 times, wont it affect performance?

Comment: It depends on how we use it, generally we provide `load more` options instead of showing 50 products altogether., if at all someone wants to reduce the overhead, its better to use plain JS

Comment: I guess questioner is using magento, and default product listing page will not have load more option until he is using customized theme. Generally, if there is no load more option it will affect performance right?

Comment: I was not ware that the OP is using Magento, since OP has not tagged it and yeah...it might affect if there is no such option

Comment: yes Iam using magento. But the jquery code suggested does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a much, much easier way to do this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery(".product-image").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().show();
  }, function() {
    $(this).next().hide();
  });

});
```

**Demo:** [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/bocofav/1/embed?js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Ashi,

try using 
var bla = jQuery(input[id*='prod_id']).val();

instead of

var bla = jQuery('#prod_id').val();

This will give you all the hidden inputs so loop all of them and bind the mouseover event.

For example:

jQuery(input[id*='prod_id']).each(function(){

var bla = jQuery(this).val();

//carry out your logic..
// you can use jquery().live('mouseover'function(){}) for dynamically created html
});

Hope this will work!!

Cheers!!

Comment: .live is deprecated, use .on :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function handler(ev) {
    var target = $(ev.target);
    var elId = target.attr('id');
    if( target.is(".el") ) {
       alert('The mouse was over'+ elId );
    }
}
$(".el").mouseleave(handler);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/dJgf4/